# Get Object Key as String by Dot Property Accessors

Tags: javascript

Given an object e.g. `let x = {y: 123, z: 321};` I wonder if there is an elegant way to get a field name as string, e.g. `x.y.name() === 'y'`.

I know this could be done with Object.keys and Object.values (`Object.keys(x)[Object.values(x).indexOf(x.y)]`) but there must be a better way.

Comment: the value does not know about its location.

Comment: `x.y.name()` statement already have `y ` why to compare with `'y'`? you can use [Object.hasOwnProperty('y')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Comment: why not use `'y' in x`, you just want to use it for comparison right ?

Comment: What is your use case or higher level problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I don't want to have the string key flying around, neither as an additional constant nor as a string somewhere. Basically for static code analysis, when the name should change. In Java I could just use `MyEnum.MyValue.name()` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no better way than to use `Object.keys(x)[Object.values(x).indexOf(x.y)]`, which will only work if there are no duplicate values and no value is `NaN`, and there are not both `+0` and `-0` values. So not a very stable solution. If its neccessary to reference the names of an objects fields, it might make sense to use constants for the keys:

```
const fieldName1 = 'abc';
let object = {[fieldName1]: 123};
```